# How can I make an input box filter a list of names on a letter by letter basis--both "forwards" and "backwards"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a follow up to this question: [How can I successively filter the choices in a list on a letter by letter basis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72479041/how-can-i-successively-filter-the-choices-in-a-list-on-a-letter-by-letter-basis)

The script I'm using (thank you, Michal), does eliminate choices as I'm typing in successive letters in the list of names. However, if I want to back out by a letter or so, because, for instance, I've made a typo, I have to erase all of the letters in the input box which causes it to repopulate the entire list. For example, if in the following part of the larger list,

```
<li>New Brunswick</li>
<li>New Hampshire</li>
<li>New Jersey</li>
<li>New Mexico</li>
<li>New York</li>
```

I accidentally type "New G" instead of "New H", I can't just delete the letter "G" and the preceding space to get all the "New" choices in the list to repopulate. Instead, I have to erase everything and have the entire list (of 63 states, provinces and territories) reappear and start from scratch. Is there something that can be added to the script that will enable the list to partially repopulate based on the remaining letters in the input box?

Here is a live version of the list [https://www.sodyot.com/where_we've_been.htm](https://www.sodyot.com/where_we%27ve_been.htm)

and here is an example of a site that does what I want. https://www.campendium.com/

Here is Michal's script:

```
function myFunction() {
    var value = document.getElementById("myInput").value.toUpperCase();
    var myUL = document.getElementById("myUL");
    for (var elem of myUL.getElementsByTagName("li")) {
        if (elem.innerText.toUpperCase().startsWith(value)) {
          elem.style.display = "";
        } else {
          elem.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

As always, thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Html ```datalist``` is exactly what you want, but if you want customization you can use js,, your function seems to be ok, what event are you listening to?

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your suggestion. That might work better, especially on smaller screens. As it currently is, there is no event listener on the input box. The entire list is present on the page, the input box just filters items on the list as each letter is typed in. The state, province, or territory names are clicked to open a drop down box of links. If I did it the way you suggest, How would I get  the list of links for only the chosen state (or province or territory) to appear below it?

Comment: ```as each letter is typed in``` this requires an event such as ```keyup```, ```keydown```, ```input``` or ```change```  i think you're using on of them and this is a misunderstanding,, about ```datalist``` you need to add a text input and set ```list``` attr of it to your datalist, this way html himself will do the filtering